# ID increment 0001 + 1 shows 2

Tags: php, mysql

I've got simple database with IDs `0001`, `0002` etc.
I have to get my last ID and add 1 at the end.

I am saving it to `$_SESSION['part_number'] = $part_number + 1;` 
I don't know why I get 2 result if the ID is `0001`.
Same if the ID is `0010` etc, I would like to have it always LAST ID + 1 with the 00 at the front.

Comment: You really need those 000 at the beginning? Why you need them?  Thats not so nice....
I think the problem is that you saved your data as integer. Integer will remove useless 0. May you should store them as strings, but then AI won't work...

Comment: don't store leading 0's anywhere, only display them when needed (use `php.net/str_pad` and friends)

Comment: Just use 1, 2 etc... Integers can't have 000 in the beginning since they are useless.

Comment: yeah, i need the 000, the person who I made it for want it with 000.

Comment: The person who you made this for needs it stored like this in the database?? I highly doubt that, people with such requirements NEVER visit data directly, but usually through some UI.

Comment: @zog learn to distinguish between _internal representation_ and _presentation format_

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
$part_number = (int)$part_number;
$part_number++
$_SESSION['part_number'] = str_pad($part_number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: no, really, don't.   Follow the advice you're getting in the comments and don't store leading zeroes anywhere.

Comment: That wasn't the question though, whilst I agree it's not best practice, sometimes it's what you've got to work with.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a dynamically typed language. To avoid strange conversions, do not ever use leading zeros, especially for the database, you just make your life harder. (An `AUTO_INCREMENT` field does all the job for you, and you can add the leading zeros on MySQL side if you really need to). There also could be a problem that numbers starting with `0` are interpreted as **octal** (base 8) numbers if you used PHP.

To do all this on SQL side,

Just change the ID field to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and use the MySQL function `LPAD()` to retrieve the data with leading zeros.

`SELECT LPAD(id, 4, '0') AS id FROM your_table_name WHERE ...`

Answer (score -1):

Use `STR_PAD_LEFT`

```
echo str_pad( $_SESSION['part_number'], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT ); //0002
```

OR

```
echo str_pad( $part_number+1, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT ); //0002
```